# Jenkins not starting in docker (Dockerfile included)

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am attempting to build a simple app with Jenkins in a docker container. I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

# Install dependencies for Flask app.
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install -y vim
RUN sudo apt-get install -y curl 
RUN sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install flask

# Install dependencies for Jenkins (Java).
        # Install Java 1.8.
RUN sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties debconf-utils
RUN sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN echo "oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true" | sudo debconf-set-selections
RUN sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
        # Install, start Jenkins.
RUN sudo apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | apt-key add -
RUN echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install -y jenkins
RUN sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start

COPY ./app /app

CMD ["python3","/app/main.py"]
```

I run this container with the following:

```
docker build -t jenkins_test .
docker run --name jenkins_test_container -tid -p 5000:5000 -p 8080:8080 jenkins_test:latest
```

I am able to start flask and install Jenkins, however, when running, Jenkins is not running. `curl localhost:8080` is not successful.

In the log output, I am able to see:

```
Correct java version found
 * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins [ OK ]
```

However, it's still not running.

I can ssh into the container and manually run `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start` to start it, but I want it to start on `docker run` or `docker build`.

I have also tried putting `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start` in the `CMD` portion of the Docker file:

```
CMD python3 /app/main.py; sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start
```

With this, I am able to curl Flask, but still not Jenkins.

**How can I get Jenkins to start automatically?**

Comment: You may want to have a look at the official Jenkins docker image: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md You can either use it or get some ideas how to install Jenkins in docker if you want to run your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some points that you need to be aware of:

1. No need to use `sudo` as the default user is root already.
2. In order to run multiple service in the same container you need to use any kind of service manager like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). Jenkins is not running because the `CMD` is the main entry point for your container so only flask should be running. Check the following [link](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) in order to know how to start multiple service in docker.

   > `RUN` will be executed only during the build process unlike `CMD` which will be executed each time you start a container from that image.
3. Combine all the `RUN` lines together as possible in order to minimize the build layers which lead to a smaller docker image.

Regarding the usage of this:

```
CMD python3 /app/main.py; sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start
```

It does not work for you because this command `python3 /app/main.py` is not running as a background process so this command `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start` wont run until the previous command is done.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to get this to work by starting Jenkins in the `CMD` portion, but needed to start Jenkins before Flask since Flask would continuously run and the next command would never execute:

Did not work:

```
CMD python3 /app/main.py; sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start
```

**This did work:**

```
CMD sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start; python3 /app/main.py
```

EDIT:

I believe putting it in the `RUN` portion would not work because container would build but not save the any running services. I'm not sure if containers can be saved and loaded with running processes like that but I might be wrong. Would appreciate clarification if so.

It seems like a thing that *should* be in `RUN` so if anyone knows why that didn't work or some best practices, would also appreciate the info.